# Converting query into Laravel Query Builder with Count, filter, and WhereIn

Tags: mysql, laravel, postgresql, laravel-query-builder

I have a query and I tried to convert it to laravel query builder style.
However I couldn't succeed.

This is my query

```
SELECT
  count(*)
    FILTER (WHERE order_status_id IN (5, 4, 15))        AS ready_for_delivery,
  count(*)
    FILTER (WHERE order_status_id IN (6))               AS out_for_delivery,
  count(*)
    FILTER (WHERE order_status_id IN (4, 10, 9, 12, 7)) AS completed_order,
  count(*)
    FILTER (WHERE order_status_id IN (11, 16, 17, 13))  AS waiting_for_cancellation_return_change
FROM order_item_histories;
```

This is what I got from http://www.midnightcowboycoder.com/ which obviously doesn't work. But it is a starting point

```
DB::table('order_item_histories')
        ->selectSub('count', 'ready_for_delivery')
        ->selectSub('FILTER', 'ready_for_delivery')
        ->selectSub('count', 'out_for_delivery')
        ->selectSub('FILTER', 'out_for_delivery')
        ->selectSub('count', 'completed_order')
        ->selectSub('FILTER', 'completed_order')
        ->selectSub('count', 'waiting_for_cancellation_return_change')
        ->selectSub('FILTER', 'waiting_for_cancellation_return_change')
        ->get();
```

This query works but it is just raw. I know no harm but..

```
        $aa = DB::table('order_item_histories')
            ->select(DB::raw('count(*)
    FILTER (WHERE order_status_id IN (5, 4, 15))        AS ready_for_delivery,
  count(*)
    FILTER (WHERE order_status_id IN (6))               AS out_for_delivery,
  count(*)
    FILTER (WHERE order_status_id IN (4, 10, 9, 12, 7)) AS completed_order,
  count(*)
    FILTER (WHERE order_status_id IN (11, 16, 17, 13))  AS waiting_for_cancellation_return_change'))
            ->get();
```

Comment: if it ain't broke, don't fix it

Comment: @Ohgodwhy That's one approach :)

Comment: I think multiple calls like this will work `->selectSub('count(*) FILTER (WHERE order_status_id IN (5, 4, 15))', 'ready_for_delivery')` but it's perfectly fine to write raw queries is this case, just beware of SQL injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
DB::table('order_item_histories')
    ->selectRaw('count(*) FILTER (WHERE order_status_id IN (?, ?, ?)) AS ready_for_delivery', [5, 4, 15])
    ->selectRaw('count(*) FILTER (WHERE order_status_id IN (?)) AS out_for_delivery', [6])
    ->selectRaw('count(*) FILTER (WHERE order_status_id IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)) AS completed_order', [4, 10, 9, 12, 7])
    ->selectRaw('count(*) FILTER (WHERE order_status_id IN (?, ?, ?, ?))  AS waiting_for_cancellation_return_change', [11, 16, 17, 13])
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `case` instead of `filter`

```
$users = DB::table('order_item_histories')
                 ->select(DB::raw('SUM(CASE WHEN order_status_id IN (5, 4, 15) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ready_for_delivery'))
                 ->select(DB::raw('SUM(CASE WHEN order_status_id IN (6) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS out_for_delivery'))
                 ->select(DB::raw('SUM(CASE WHEN order_status_id IN (4, 10, 9, 12, 7) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS completed_order'))
                 ->select(DB::raw('SUM(CASE WHEN order_status_id IN (11, 16, 17, 13) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS waiting_for_cancellation_return_change'))
                 ->get();
```

Comment: Didn't give me expected output.

Comment: What result did you got